# How add data using push() in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to ask, how to add data using push(), after user click the button. Can someone help me?

```
function myCtrl($scope){
$scope form ={companyName :"company1",companyAddress:"company address",staff[{name:"men",id:"123"}]}
function myCtrl($scope){
enter code here
$scope.addDetail=function(){
$scope.form.push({companyName:$scope.comName,companyAddress:$scope.comAddress, staff.name:$scope.nameStaff, staff.id: $scope.idStaff});
}}

<input type="text" ng-model="comName" />
<input type="text" ng-model="comAddress" />
<input type="text" ng-model="nameStaff" />
<input type="text" ng-model="idStaff" />
<button ng-click=addDetail()>add<button>
```

Comment: add this directive to your button's html.  ng-click="addDetail()".  This will call the addDetail function defined on your scope object.

Comment: $scope.form.push(******); // i dont know,how to apply this code
}}

Comment: Push what? you haven't shown what expected results are or really explained exactly what it is you are trying to do as it relates to the code. `$scope.form` is an object and `push()` is an array method. Objects don't have a push method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form` should be an array (array has `push` method). It goes like this:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="comName" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="comAddress" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="nameStaff" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="idStaff" />
  <button ng-click=addDetail()>add
  </button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.form = [{
    companyName: "company1",
    companyAddress: "company address",
    staff: [{
      name: "men",
      id: "123"
    }]
  }]

  $scope.addDetail = function() {
    $scope.form.push({
      companyName: $scope.comName,
      companyAddress: $scope.comAddress,
      staff: [{
        name: $scope.nameStaff,
        id: $scope.idStaff
      }]
    });
  }

}
```

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/royscn4j/